# Dividing a Rectangle into 3 Identical Triangles

Tags: puzzle

I got this puzzle and would like to ask for your opinion. Is it possible to divide a rectangle into 3 identical triangles? If yes, how ? I couldn't do it. If no, why? Thanks. (this is a puzzle for fun!).

Comment: How many times can we cut the rectangle and rearrange the pieces ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope! In fact, we can say much more: [Monsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsky%27s_theorem) states that you can't divide a parallelogram into an odd number of triangles of equal area. The nice thing about this result is that it applies to triangles having arbitrary angles.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316594900493) Samuel Maltby paper shows that it is impossible to divide a rectangle into 3 identical pieces that are not rectangular.